# QR Factorization for Inconsistent Linear System

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

I am trying to recreate the problem found [here](http://homepages.se.edu/kfrinkle/files/2014/06/CS3513Fall2006homework8solutions.pdf) on finding the least squares solution to an inconsistent linear system via QR factorization. Can someone explain the part about adding on vectors so that Q will span $R^5$? When I try to go through this in Matlab using the qr built-in function, my new R matrix is a 5x5 instead of a 5x3. Below is the code that I have thus far. From what I can tell, the only error is that my new R matrix is coming out as the wrong dimension.

```
A = [3 -1 2; 4 1 0; -3 2 1; 1 1 5; -2 0 3];
b = [10; 10; -5; 15; 0];
[Q,R]=qr(A,0)
% Add on additional vector to Q in order to span R^4
Qt = [Q(1,1) Q(1,2) Q(1,3) 1 0; Q(2,1) Q(2,2) Q(2,3) 0 1; Q(3,1) Q(3,2) Q(3,3) 0 0; Q(4,1) Q(4,2) Q(4,3) 0 0; Q(5,1) Q(5,2) Q(5,3) 0 0];
[Qnew,Rnew]=qr(Qt,0);
% Multiply Qnew with given b:
Qnewtran = transpose(Qnew);
bnew = Qnewtran*b;
x = Rnew\bnew
```

Comment: So, you're saying that this is happening because my A matrix isn't full rank?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Matlab function qr when applied to matrix $A$ (i.e. [Q,R]=qr(A)) makes the QR decomposition
$$A=QR$$ 
with $Q$ a $5\times 5$ orthogonal matrix, $R$ a  $5\times 3$ upper triangular and **returns $Q,R$**. Note that $Q,R$ can be decomposed as
$$Q=[\matrix{Q_1 & Q_2}]\\R=\left[\matrix{R_1\\0}\right]$$
where $Q_1$ is a matrix consisting of the the first 3 columns of $Q$, $Q_2$ is a matrix consisting of  the rest 2 columns of $Q$ and $R_1$ a $3\times 3$ upper triangular matrix which is invertible if $rank(A)=3$. Thus, the decomposition can be simplified as
$$A=QR=[\matrix{Q_1 & Q_2}]\left[\matrix{R_1\\0}\right]=Q_1R_1$$
Since $Q$ is orthogonal it holds true that $Q_1^TQ_1=\mathbb{I}_3$. Now it is straightforward to prove that the  solution of the equation is  given by
$$x=R_1^{-1}Q_1^Tb$$

So your MATLAB code should be something like that

[Q,R]=qr(A);

Q1=Q(:,1:3);

R1=R(1:3,:);

x=inv(R1)*Q1'*b;

Comment: Or, you can use [Q1,R1]=qr(A,0)